# If ID has class, set attribute of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to detect if a class is present and, if so, set the background attribute of another element. This is what I have but it's not working.

```
if(jQuery("#slider-banner").hasClass('living-nutrients'))
    {
        jQuery("#home-middle-first").css("background-image","[path to new background image]");
    }
```

BTW - My next step is for this to detect it whenever the ID "slider-banner" changes, but so far I can't even get it to work once on page load. Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thanks!

**EDIT:** I changed from .attr to .css as instructed. Makes sense... but still not working. I've tried adding console.log message within the IF statement and got nothing also. Does that give anyone any more ideas?

**Example HTML where class changes:**

```
<img id="slider-banner" class="living-nutrients" src="[image path]">
```

**Example HTML where I want to change background image:**

```
<div class="home-middle-one-third" id="home-middle-first">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

For everyone who said it "should work"... you are right! Turns out that, as written, it doesn't like being in the footer of the page, but when I moved it to the head, presto!

The final piece of this puzzle is to have it detect and evaluate based on the #slider-banner changing, (or more accurately, which class is present for the ID'd area), not just the page loading, as is currently.

The ID is for one element of a slide within a slider. There are three possible classes I could assign to the ID depending on which slide is visible. So I need the script to evaluate every time a slide changes.

Any ideas? Thank you all!

Comment: Maybe, css solution: `#slider-banner.living-nutrients + #home-middle-first { background-image: url(...) }` would be enough for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`background-image` is a element's style property, not its own one.

So `.css("background-image","[path to new background image]");`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I understand that .css is correct, but even after changing that it still does not work. I've also tried to console.log a message within the IF statement and get nothing. Does that give you any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your code should work. Add `if (!jQuery) console.log("no jquery till now")` check.

Comment: Yeah, it took moving it to the <head>. I had it in the footer area before, but it works now. Thanks. Any thoughts on the latest update?

Comment: Try to listen to your heart... erm, slider events. Maybe, it's easy. If not, use check in function called periodically (with `setInterval`)

Answer (score 2):

Almost!

```
if(jQuery("#slider-banner").hasClass('living-nutrients'))
{
    jQuery("#home-middle-first").css("background-image","[path to new background image]");
}
```

`css` is the correct function to set a CSS attribute.
The `attr` will set an HTML attribute. `<div attr='attr value'>`

**Edit**
I'm kind of guessing about the functionality of your script here in the following example.
When you set the `background-image` of a HTML node, that's all it does is set the background image. You must also set the width and height accordingly, to all the node to be large enough to even see the background of the node. Background images will not automatically resize the node.

```
var slider = jQuery("#slider-banner"); // jQuery("#slider-banner") is slow, so we save it to a var if we use it more than once
console.log(slider); // should be this in Chrome: [<img id="slider-banner" class="living-nutrients" src="[image path]">]
if(slider.hasClass('living-nutrients'))
{
    jQuery("#home-middle-first").css({
        "background-image":"url("+slider.attr('src')+")", // url() for good meassures
        //"background-image":slider.css('background-image'), //try this if that doesn't work
        "height":slider.height(),
        "width":slider.width()
    });
}
```

[Here is a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewjackson/ahxQe/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree with your answer and have changed the source accordingly, but it still does not work. I've added additional details to the post, including the affected html. Does that give you any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I have modified my answer, please review

Comment: Before I went to bed I had moved the script from the footer to the <head> area and it worked. It evaluates on page load, now I'm just working out how to have it evaluate every time a slide in the slider changes. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to explain all the details of what I'm going for in a way that doesn't just muddy up the question. The div that is getting a background replace already has it's height and width set. In the complete scenario, what I am trying to do is set the same background that is also set if there is a mouse hover. There's basically three menu items below the slider with a hover effect, but I am trying to set the background to the hover background when the corresponding slide is visible in the slider as well. I'd be happy to PM you a lin

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
jQuery("#home-middle-first").css("background-image","url([path])");
```

Comment: this is actually correct as well, but `url()` is not required in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree with your answer and have changed the source accordingly, but it still does not work. I've added additional details to the post, including the affected html. Does that give you any other ideas? Thanks!